# IntegrityError at /api/order/create NOT NULL constraint failed: store_order.product_id

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create Order via Api request with related keys, product and user id's. But getting an error that they cannot be null, although they're not null.

model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
    orderPrice = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Принят на обработку')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'user', 'status', 'orderPrice']
        depth = 1
```

view.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def OrderCreateView(request):
    order_serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if order_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        order_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(order_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

and finally my api request

```
  {
        "product": 1,
        "user": 3,
        "status": "Принят на обработку",
        "orderPrice": 30000
    }
```

This code worked sometime but i did couple changes and now it getting an error. I tried to remigrate all my models, and requested like that "user_id", "product_id". But keeps getting the error

Comment: make user and Product are null=True and blank=True then you will not get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi**
the problem of your code is your serializer because you mention a `depth` of 1 and you send a JSON in your POST functiona JSON in coherent.
Your json should contain all the attributes of your foreign keys like this:

```
 {
        "product": {
...attributes of product
},
        "user":  {
...attributes of user
},
        "status": "Принят на обработку",
        "orderPrice": 30000
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. You solved my problem, i just created separate serializer without depth, so get method has own serializer now. I tried to give null=True to foreign keys, but i was getting null.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare the product field as nullable, because `null` is False by delfault:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    [...]
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    [...]
```

I also removed `related_name`, as to retrieve the order of a product, you had to call `product.product`. Now you retrieve it using `product.order`.